# Index was outside of the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

So i have a problem but im not sure why.

```
    public static int Suurin(int[,] luku)
    {
        int max = luku[0, 0];
        for (int i = 0; i < luku.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < luku.Length; i++)
            {
                if (max < luku[i, j])  // ERROR LINE
                    max = luku[i, j];

            }
```

so i just dunno how to figure this out can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the error? what do you expect it to do? What have you tried doing to figure out or fix the error?

Answer (score 9):

replace

```
for (int j = 0; j < luku.Length; i++)
```

with

```
for (int j = 0; j < luku.Length; j++)
```

I've made that mistake more times than I'd like to admit.

EDIT:

While what I posted above is still correct, you should be using [GetUpperBound()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you're trying to get the maximum value of any item in any dimension.

```
int max = luku[0, 0];
for (int i = 0; i <= luku.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= luku.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        if (max < luku[i, j])
            max = luku[i, j];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

For two-dimensional array, its Length is multiplication of row and column (equal to total number of elements)

For example,

```
int[,] luku = {{1,2,3}, {2,3,4}, {2,3,4}};
```

`luku.Length` = row * column = 3*3 = **9**

Another example,

```
int[,] luku = {{1,2,3,4}, {2,3,4,5}, {2,3,4,6}};
```

`luku.Length` = row * column = 3*4 = **12**

Therefore you cannot use `luku.Length` in nested For loop  to iterate all elements in two dimensional array.
Because you will have **IndexOutofRange** exception with out of range row and column index.

By using Jodrell methods,

> `luku.OfType<int>().Max();`

You can get the maximum value of the two dimensional array with

```
   public static int Suurin(int[,] luku)
    {
        int max = luku.OfType<int>().Max();
```

Comment: Because I have less than 50 reputations, therefore I cannot comment in other posts,
tencntraze,
your inner For loop should be <= luku.GetUpperBound(1) to include also those items in largest column
`for (int j = 0; j <= luku.GetUpperBound(1); j++)`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own loops, you could just do

```
luku.OfType<int>().Max();
```

---

In general, avoid multi-dimensional arrays and use jagged arrays or some other collection. Multi-dimensional arrays suck on many levels.

Comment: Also a good point, and to further note that jagged arrays are better, take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)